# Maximizing the overall sum of K disjoint and contiguous subsets of size L among N positive numbers

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset, np-hard

I'm trying to find an algorithm to find `K` disjoint, contiguous subsets of size `L` of an array `x` of real numbers that maximize the sum of the elements.

Spelling out the details, X is a set of N positive real numbers:
    `X={x[1],x[2],...x[N]} where x[j]>=0 for all j=1,...,N.`

A contiguous subset of length L called `S[i]` is defined as L consecutive members of X starting at position `n[i]` and ending at position `n[i]+L-1`:
`S[i] = {x[j] | j=n[i],n[i]+1,...,n[i]+L-1} = {x[n[i]],x[n[i]+1],...,x[n[i]+L-1]}.`

Two of such subsets `S[i]` and `S[j]` are called pairwise disjoint (non-overlapping) if `|n[i]-n[j]|>=L`. In other words, they don't contain any identical members of X.

Define the summation of the members of each subset:

```
SUM[i] = x[n[i]]+x[n[i]+1]+...+x[n[i]+L-1];
```

The goal is find K contiguous and disjoint(non-overlapping) subsets `S[1],S[2],...,S[K]` of length L such that `SUM[1]+SUM[2]+...+SUM[K]` is maximized.

Comment: Forgot to mention that N > K*L so that the K subsets will not cover all N elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by dynamic programming. Let `M[i]` be the best solution only for the first `i` elements of `x`. Then:

```
M[i] = 0 for i < L
M[i] = max(M[i-1], M[i-L] + sum(x[i-L+1] + x[i-L+2] + ... + x[i]))
```

The solution to your problem is `M[N]`.

When you code it, you can incrementally compute the sum (or simply pre-compute all the sums) leading to an O(`N`) solution in both space and time.

If you have to find exactly `K` subsets, you can extend this, by defining `M[i, k]` to be the optimal solution with `k` subsets on the first `i` elements. Then:

```
M[i, k] = 0 for i < k * L or k = 0.
M[i, k] = max(M[i-1, k], M[i-L, k-1] + sum(x[i-L+1] + ... + x[i])
```

The solution to your problem is `M[N, K]`.

This is a 2d dynamic programming solution, and has time and space complexity of O(`NK`) (assuming you use the same trick as above for avoiding re-computing the sum).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. M[N,K] finds the maximum summation. To find the best subsets, I guess we should to backtracking from M[N,K] to M[1,0] and find the subset starting positions.